# Using navigation properties instead of LINQ Join in WebApi controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework Code First and LINQ to Entities in a Web Api Controller.

I have 3 tables that are related with the following relations/ navigation properties: (the model classes are as follows)

My Reservation class:

```
[Table("Reservations")] 
public class Reservation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReservationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }



    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    // create association table ReservationMeals
    public virtual ICollection<ReservationMealItems> ReservationMeals { get; set; }
}
```

Association class:

```
 public class ReservationMealItems
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ReservationId { get; set; }

    public int MealId { get; set; }


    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
    public virtual Meal Meal { get; set; }

}
```

Meals class:

```
[Table("Meals")]
public class Meal
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int MealTypeId { get; set; }


    public virtual MealType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuMealItem> Menus { get; set; }

    // create association table ReservationMeal
    public virtual ICollection<ReservationMealItems> ReservationMeals { get; set; }

    // one-to-one with MealPrice where MealPrice is the dependant
    public virtual MealPrice MealPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my controller to which I am passing a Date and then querying the tables in order to bring back all the meals from all the reservations made on that particular date.

```
        public IHttpActionResult GetReservationMealsForDate(DateDto date)
    {
        using (var context = new CafeteriaContext())
        {
            var reservationMeals = from p in context.Reservations
                                   where p.Date == date.Date
                                   join d in context.ReservationMeals
                                   on p.ReservationId equals d.ReservationId
                                   select new SimpleId
                                   {
                                       Id = d.MealId
                                   };


            var meals = from p in context.Meals
                        join d in reservationMeals
                        on p.Id equals d.Id
                        select new SimpleMeal
                        {
                            Name = p.Name
                        };


            return Ok(meals.ToList());
        }
    }
```

The controller works and brings back the list of meals from all reservations made on that date but I am certain that it's not optimal.

I tried not using the JOINs and instead make use of the navigation properties but with no success. I wonder if the relations are set up correctly and if the navigation properties are placed as they should be and if yes, then how can the controller be rewritten to bring back the same result set using navigation properties.

And as a bonus question I would like to know how to write the **correct** query using LINQ method syntax as I did not succeed in writing it as such.

I am currently learning and any explanations are greatly appreciated. I have read this blog post [Coding Abel](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) from where I managed to make it work. But I am still curious to know how correct my solution is and eager to learn better alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use eagerly loading with LINQ and method `Include`. Your table ReservationMealItems have relationships to Meal and Reservation in this case you need include your entities like :

Lambda

```
var x = context.ReservationMealItems.Include(res => res.Reservation)
         .Where(dt => dt.Reservation.Date == DateTime.Now)
         .ThenInclude(meal => meal.Meal)
         .Select(d => d.Meal.Name)
         .ToList();
```

Here you find more informations [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Query Syntax

```
 var z = (from resevationMealsItems in context.ReservationMealItems
         join reservation in context.Reservation on resevationMealsItems.ReservationId equals
         reservation.ReservationId
         join meal in context.Meal on resevationMealsItems.MealId equals meal.Id
         select meal.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Since the query uses projection, it has nothing in common with eager loading. The query you wrote will work without any `Include` calls (they are ignored anyway).

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I cannot add the second `Include` since it does not recognize it. I don't know why exactly. Maybe because of the properties that are marked as `virtual`, I'm not sure.  However I get the results with the following query making use of lazy loading:   `var betterAlt = context.ReservationMeals.Where(dt => dt.Reservation.Date == date.Date).Select(d => d.Meal.Name).ToList();`

Comment: Your answer has definitely pointed me in the right direction, I know now why I have taken the long way around since I first targeted the Reservation table and then went to the others. With the nav properties and first targeting the ReservationMeal table things are shorter and more direct. And thank you for the MSDN link, it is exactly what I needed.  And since Lazy Loading seems to be dangerous and quite harmful, I will try to make more use of eager loading. And another point is that the `Include` method seems to take only a string pointing to the name of the nav prop that we want to include

Comment: Try use always leazy loading, sometimes better wrote syntax queries instead lambda using .Include. This affects performance whit bigger databases.

Comment: I think you mean use Eager Loading instead of Lazy Loading ? (virtual properties)

Comment: @SorinVasiliu Your `betterAlt` query is the right way to go. You don't need neither lazy nor eager loading because the query does not return entities. If you turn EF logging, you'll see that `betterAlt` simply generates a single SQL.